# Getting mouseEvent value on insert statement

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my insert statement that is getting a weird value, I want this to be a numeric value

Button on .pug page:

```
input(type="submit" value="Add Line" @click="addLine")
```

my insert statement with a post request

```
  output Inserted.*
  Values (
    '${req.query.quote_number || ''}',
    ((select count(quote_number) as [count]
      from quote_line
      where quote_number = ${req.query.quote_number || ''}) + 1),
    'new item line',
    getDate()
  )
```

and I am getting [object mouseEvent] as the data for req.query.quote_number

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to bind the input value using v-model? ( v-model="somevariable" )
Bind the value to a variable, then pass the variable on the @click event

Comment: Thanks for the help the passing a variable pushed me towards the answer, I’m an idiot and didn’t pass that variable through on the click event!    Should have been @click=“addLine(query_number)”

Comment: the devil is in the details